# How to disable GIL in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, celluloid

I am pretty much new to Ruby and I was working on a project to run a multithreaded ruby program implemented using celluloid library.

It seems like when I try to run the program using the command:

```
ruby program_name.rb
```

The code don't run properly and it says GIL is stopping it from making use of multiple cores. I understand GIL is a locking mechanism used by ruby interpreter, but I was wondering if there is a way to diable it with a special command to make concurrent program run.

If this is something impossible, is there any other way to execute multithreaded program in ruby / with any online editor/IDE that supports such multithreading in Ruby?

Comment: Use rubinius or jruby. They don't have the lock.

Comment: I wish I could have found one straight forward online source on how to install one of these. Can you help?

Comment: I use chruby with [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install). You just do `ruby-install jruby` and that's it for the installation.

Comment: I feel like I'm asking questions like a child but I don't know how to trigger jruby. It says jruby is installed in my system but when I try to run the program using jruby program_name.rb, it says command not found!

Comment: See the extremist's answer, he links to RVM which is another popular ruby switching tools. After reading its instructions, you should have no questions left :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use jRuby or Rubinius

I prefer `rvm` for this. See: http://rvm.io

Then run:

```
rvm get stable
rvm install jruby
```

For jRuby. Change to `rbx` for Rubinius.

Then you can switch between Ruby engines with:

```
rvm use <jruby/rbx>
```

Using `Celluloid` you ought to try both and compare them often.